Concisely map runtime variables to template parameters, for _many_ functions
Problem
I have a templated function
template <int N>
void myfunc(int a) {

    // contents compile-time optimised using N
}

which I instantiate at compile-time to make unique definitions for differing N. At runtime, I need to invoke myfunc with the template parameter informed by a user-given variable.
A verbose method would be:
void callOptimisedMyFunc(int n, int a) {
    if (n == 0) myfunc<0>(a);
    if (n == 1) myfunc<1>(a);
    if (n == 2) myfunc<2>(a);
    // ...
    if (n == MAX) myfunc<MAX>(a);
}

which is painfully long in my case, whereby MAX can be as large as 64. To make matters worse, I need to create such wrappers for about ten distinct functions with unique signatures and return types! E.g.
template <int N>
long otherFunc(string x, double y) {
    
    // ...

} 

void callOptimisedOtherFunc(int n, string x, double y) {
    if (n == 0) return otherfunc<0>(x, y);
    if (n == 1) return otherfunc<1>(x, y);
    if (n == 2) return otherfunc<2>(x, y);
    // ...
    if (n == MAX) return otherfunc<MAX>(x, y);
}

I ergo wish to perform this mapping of run-time to compile-time parameter metaprogrammatically.
Unsatisfying solution
My current unsatisfyingly verbose solution is to use log-depth macros:
#define NORETURN

#define INNER1(usernum, compnum, func, args, retcmd) \
    if (usernum == compnum) retcmd func<compnum> args;

#define INNER4(usernum, compbase, func, args, retcmd) \
    INNER1( usernum, compbase+0, func, args, retcmd ); \
    INNER1( usernum, compbase+1, func, args, retcmd ); \
    INNER1( usernum, compbase+2, func, args, retcmd ); \
    INNER1( usernum, compbase+3, func, args, retcmd );

#define INNER16(usernum, compbase, func, args, retcmd) \
    INNER4( usernum, compbase+0,  func, args, retcmd ); \
    INNER4( usernum, compbase+4,  func, args, retcmd ); \
    INNER4( usernum, compbase+8,  func, args, retcmd ); \
    INNER4( usernum, compbase+12, func, args, retcmd );

#define INNER64(usernum, func, args, retcmd) \
    INNER16( usernum, 0,  func, args, retcmd ); \
    INNER16( usernum, 16, func, args, retcmd ); \
    INNER16( usernum, 32, func, args, retcmd ); \
    INNER16( usernum, 48, func, args, retcmd );

#define CALL_OPTIMISED_FUNC(n, func, ...) \
    INNER64( n, func, (__VA_ARGS__), NORETURN );

#define CALL_AND_RETURN_OPTIMISED_FUNC(n, func, ...) \
    INNER64( n, func, (__VA_ARGS__), return );

which permits me to run:
void callOptimisedMyFunc(int N, int a) {

    CALL_OPTIMISED_FUNC( N, myfunc, a );
}

long callOptimisedOtherFunc(int N, string x, double y) {

    CALL_AND_RETURN_OPTIMISED_FUNC( N, otherfunc, x, y );
}

This is still uncomfortably verbose, and does not use all the beautiful C++ metaprograming facilities available in C++17. It also seems a shame to needlessly evaluate 64 if statements at each invocation. A more satisfying solution would be to prepare a static array of function pointers, indexed by their template parameter N.
Partial solution
If I only had a single templated function to call (i.e. only myfunc), I could use index_sequence like so:
#include <array>
#include <utility>

template<size_t... N>
constexpr auto helper_myfunc(index_sequence<N...>) {

    return array <void (*)(int), sizeof...(N)> { myfunc<N> ... };
}

constexpr auto getArrayOfMyFuncRefs() {

    return helper_myfunc( make_index_sequence<MAX>() );
}

which would allow me to concisely write
void callOptimisedMyFunc(int n, int a) {

    static auto funcs = getArrayOfMyFuncRefs();
    funcs[n](a);
}

Alas, I would need to duplicate this definition for the other functions for which I wish to map run-time parameters to compile-time ones:
template<size_t... N>
constexpr auto helper_otherfunc(index_sequence<N...>) {

    return array <long (*)(string, double), sizeof...(N)> { otherfunc<N> ... };
}

constexpr auto getArrayOfOtherFuncRefs() {

    return helper_otherfunc( make_index_sequence<MAX>() );
}

long callOptimisedOtherFunc(int n, string x, double y) {

    static auto funcs = getArrayOfOtherFuncRefs();
    return funcs[n](x, y);
}

Sought solution
I seek to generalise my getArray*() functions above to a single function which accepts any singly-integer-templated function, even with differing signatures. That would allow me to concisely define:
void callOptimisedMyFunc(int n, int a) {

    static auto funcs = getArrayOfFuncRefs(myfunc);
    funcs[n](a);
}

void callOptimisedOtherFunc(int n, string x, double y) {

    static auto funcs = getArrayOfFuncRefs(otherfunc);
    return funcs[n](x, y);
}

I am struggling to do this because I have no idea how I can pass a reference like myfunc to a function; it lacks its template syntax (i.e. <0>). My closest efforts do not compile:
template<size_t... N, typename RetType, typename... Args>
constexpr auto helper(index_sequence<N...>, ReturnType (*funcname)(Args...)) {

    return array<RetType (*)(Args...), sizeof...(N)>{ funcname<N> ... };
}

template<typename Func>
constexpr auto getArrayOfFuncRefs(Func func) {

    return helper(make_index_sequence<MAX>(), func);
}

Is there a way to achieve what I want with C++ metaprogramming, or must I fall back onto my horrible usage of macros?

"At runtime, I need to invoke myfunc with the template parameter informed by a user-given variable...." I don't think this is possible/allowed. If the decision is made at runtime by the user how can the template argument be passed at compile time.

@user12002570 the template variable is bounded; I simply instantiate each possible within the translation unit (in my application, the user will pay this compile overhead)

All you're doing is essentially passing the argument at compile time further in your question. It might look like you're supplying the info at runtime but you're not(in the templated versions)

@user12002570 I can literally call callOptimisedMyFunc(atoi(argv[2]), a), how is it not runtime?

I am talking about template arguments not call to a function. There's nothing in callOptimisedMyFunc's call that requires a compile time construct.

the function argument informs which templated function is called. The bits in my computer and the universe around will evolve so that the template parameter is causally informed by the user's runtime parameter. Why are you choosing to die on the most pedantic hill imaginable?

Also use std:: in your given examples especially when you haven't provided a [mcve]. It's hard to add std:: everywhere when trying to compile your snippets. And using namespace std; is not acceptable.

void f(); void g() { return f(); } is valid. you might get rid of retcmd in your MACRO.

@Jarod42 valid but it gives annoying "return in void function" errors with older compilers - annoying!

Error or warning? I hope than that old compiler has flag to disable it... :-/

Have you thought about using a switch statement and looking at the resulting assembly? Optimizing compilers may generate a branch table, which essentially will have the same effect as an array of function pointers. In other words, you're not evaluating 64 ifs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement

@Jarod42 oops warning, but I think a superfluous macro flag is an acceptable price to pay to preclude the warning altogether

@zoravur that's a good point; my original implementation was indeed a giant switch. I still wish to avoid the macro boilerplate however

One way to transform runtime value to compile time value is to use std::variant, and then use std::visit for the dispatch:
template <size_t Max>
constexpr auto to_integral_constant_var(std::size_t n) {
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>( std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        using ResType = std::variant<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>...>;

        return std::array<ResType, sizeof...(Is)>{{
            std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}...
        }}[n];
    }(std::make_index_sequence<Max>());
}

Mostly the same as your helper function, but to have
std::variant<
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>,
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1>,
    //..
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Max - 1>,
>;

Then the wrapping can be done as follow:
template <std::size_t N>
void myfunc(int a) {
    //...
}

void CallOptimizedMyFunc(std::size_t n, int a)
{
    std::visit([&](auto N){ myfunc<N()>(a); },
        to_integral_constant_var<Max>(n));
}

Demo

This is amazing! Ideally I would like to reduce the boilerplate (without using macros) inside CallOptimizedMyFunc() since such a function must exist for every of my ~10 templated functions, but this certainly achieves my goals functionally

Something along these lines perhaps (not tested):
// Need one of these for each function template
template <int N>
struct MyFuncWrapper {
  static void call(int a) { myFunc<N>(a); }
};

template <template <int N> class Wrapper, typename... Args, size_t... Is>
void CallOptimizedHelper(std::index_sequence<Is...>, int n, Args&&... args) {
  ((n==Is ? (void)Wrapper<Is>::call(std::forward<Args>(args)...) : (void)0), ...);
}

template <template <int N> class Wrapper, typename... Args>
void CallOptimized(int n, Args&&... args) {
  CallOptimizedHelper<Wrapper>(
      std::make_index_sequence<MAX>{}, n,
      std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

Then you call it as
CallOptimized<MyFuncWrapper>(/*n=*/1, /*a=*/2);


Interesting! Can you explain why the wrapper class is necessary? Since I'd have to define the class/method for every inner function anyway, is there a more concise method using bespoke functions? E.g. callOptimized_myfunc(...)

Wrapper can be modified to take std::integral_constant to pass N, and lambda can be used Demo

Because you can pass a class template as a template template parameter, but can't easily pass a function template. callOptimized_myfunc could just define the wrapper, and pass it along to CallOptimized
